# Why does Angular add `cdk-overlay-container` to the body?

Tags: angular

Why `overlay-container` is added to body instead `app-root`? As I noticed this container is used to display `mat-select` options or `mat-menu` options and other features.

I have tried to change position of this container inside `app-root` element:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CustomOverlayContainer extends OverlayContainer implements OnDestroy {
    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) _document: any) {
        super(_document);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        super.ngOnDestroy();
    }

    getRootElement(): Element {
        return this._document.querySelector('app-root');
    }

    protected _createContainer(): void {
        super._createContainer();
        this._appendToRootComponent();
    }

    private _appendToRootComponent(): void {
        if (!this._containerElement) {
            return;
        }

        const rootElement = this.getRootElement();
        const parent = rootElement || this._document.body;
        parent.appendChild(this._containerElement);
    }
}
```

And root module is:

```
{ provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: CustomOverlayContainer },
```

Comment: Look right, do you have any  errors?

Comment: These is no,  I tried to change place of container. But Angular creates this again in the en d of body